# Can't import openai in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, openai-api

I have Node 16.13.1 installed and I installed openai globally with 'npm install -g openai'.
I imported the packages inside my script using:

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai')
```

However, when I ran my script, I got this error:

```
PS D:\Projects\OpenAI-Chat> node conversation.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'openai'
Require stack:
- D:\Projects\OpenAI-Chat\conversation.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\OpenAI-Chat\conversation.js:1:38)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\Projects\\OpenAI-Chat\\conversation.js' ]
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to install it locally with `npm i openai`

Comment: I wonder why installing globally doesn't work though?

Comment: Because Node.js doesn't search in the global folder for dependencies for the local project. Global installation is for global executables and its dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install it locally with

```
npm i openai
```

because Node.js doesn't search in the global folder for dependencies for the local project. Global installation is for global executables and its dependencies.